# Running a table through a PHP loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I have a table showing the list of categories and subcategories, using a function to loop through the parent/child tree. Here is the markup of the script:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS; ?></td>
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_TOTAL_WEIGHT; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

<?php
function category_list( $category_parent_id = 0 )
{
    // build our category list only once
    static $cats;

    if ( ! is_array( $cats ) )
    {
        $sql  = 'select cd.categories_name,c.categories_id, c.parent_id, c.sort_order from ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES . ' c, ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . ' cd where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id';
        $res  = tep_db_query( $sql );
        $cats = array();

        while ( $cat = tep_db_fetch_array( $res ) )
        {
            $cats[] = $cat;
        }
    }

    // populate a list items array
    $list_items = array();

    foreach ( $cats as $cat )
    {
        // if not a match, move on
        if ( ( int ) $cat['parent_id'] !== ( int ) $category_parent_id )
        {
            continue;
        }

        // open the list item
        $list_items[] = '<tr class="dataTableRow">';
        $list_items[] = '<td class="dataTableContent"><li>';

        // construct the category link

        $list_items[] = $cat['categories_name'];

        // recurse into the child list
        $list_items[] = category_list( $cat['categories_id'] );

        // close the list item
        $list_items[] = '</li></td>';
        $list_items[] = '</tr>';
    }

    // convert to a string
    $list_items = implode( '', $list_items );

    // if empty, no list items!
    if ( '' == trim( $list_items ) )
    {
        return '';
    }

    // ...otherwise, return the list
    return '<ul>' . $list_items . '</ul>';
}  

echo category_list();
?>
        <td class="dataTableContent"></td>
</table>
```

At the moment this currently prints the `<tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">` and both the `<td class="dataTableHeadingContent">`correctly, but for the `<td class="dataTableContent">`, it is only printing the tag in the function correctly. How would I print both the dataTableContent tags correctly, and keep them both in the loop?
[image]

Comment: Please properly indent your code so that it is better to read.

Comment: your question is vague, please elaborate more

Comment: try to use MVC or alteast move the logical part separate from presentation

Comment: it's hard to read your code with that presentation. and another note, you are echo'ing out a `ul` inside a table, that will not display properly. wrap it in a table cell `<td>`.

Comment: two rows for the content means?  If you give sample inputs, and the output you are looking for and the output you are getting it would be easy for every to understand

Comment: Consider what happens on a nested item tree - you'll be producing hTML that has rows nested inside rows nested inside rows. The html is going to be highly invalid.

Comment: Should I post a picture to show what the current output is?

Comment: some sample inputs and the picture will be OK

Comment: i suggest switching to mvc too, this is all a mess.

Comment: zoom the relevant part and upload, cannot see.

Comment: Yeah, that image is ok.  Now what kind of output you want?

Comment: I want it to print the list, but with each element of the list, in it's own `<td>`, a bit like what @daiscog has shown below, but not quite like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your recursive use of the function `category_list` you will be outputting `<tr>` elements *inside* `<li>`s.  This is invaild HTML.

Also, each `<tr>` in the body will only have one cell, whereas the `<tr>` in the header row has two cells.

You should consider how the output should look, then write your code to account for that, and follow the flow through to see what is being written out.  Also, check the actual HTML source returned to your browser, not how your browser renders it.  Note that different browsers will render invalid HTML differently.

Also, (not related to your problem) consider replacing the `border`, `width`, `cellspacing`, `cellpadding` and `align` HTML attributes with CSS instead.  Another consideration would be to use the `<head>` and `<tbody>` elements as additional semantic markup.

**Further Explanation**

Your problem is essentially these lines:

```
    // open the list item
    $list_items[] = '<tr class="dataTableRow">';
    $list_items[] = '<td class="dataTableContent"><li>';

    // construct the category link

    $list_items[] = $cat['categories_name'];

    // recurse into the child list
    $list_items[] = category_list( $cat['categories_id'] );

    // close the list item
    $list_items[] = '</li></td>';
    $list_items[] = '</tr>';
```

Every iteration of your loop is creating a new `tr` element!  Try this instead:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS; ?></td>
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_TOTAL_WEIGHT; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dataTableRow">
    <td class="dataTableContent">
<?php
function category_list( $category_parent_id = 0 )
{
    // NOTE THE ADDITIION OF THE PARENT ID:
    $sql  = 'select cd.categories_name,c.categories_id, c.parent_id, c.sort_order from ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES . ' c, ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . ' cd where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id AND c.parent_id='.$category_parent_id;
    $res  = tep_db_query( $sql );
    $cats = array();

    while ( $cat = tep_db_fetch_array( $res ) )
    {
        $cats[] = $cat;
    }

   if (count($cats) == 0)
   {
      // There are no categories to list
      return '';
   }

    // Create a list HTML string
    $list = '<ul>';

    foreach ( $cats as $cat )
    {
        // open the list item
        $list .= '<li>';

        // construct the category link

        $list .= $cat['categories_name'];

        // recurse into the child list
        $list .= category_list( $cat['categories_id'] );

        // close the list item
        $list .= '</li>';
    }

    // close and return the list
    $list .= '</ul>';
    return $list;

}  

echo category_list();
?>
        </td>
        <td class="dataTableContent"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that further improvements can be made regarding data and presentation logic separation.  You don't necessarily need to adopt a full-scale MVC framework; just use OOP to encapsulate your SQL queries within classes which represent your database entities.

**EDIT**

*Following the specification that each category should be in its own `<td>`.*

This requires the removal of the list elements.  A `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` elements as children; it cannot contain `<tr>` children.  A `<td>` MUST be a child of a `<tr>`.  It is not allowed anywhere else.  A `<tr>` can only be a child of a `<thead>`, `<tbody>`* or `<tfoot>`.  These rules are all defined in the [HTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html).

Therefore, the following is the sort of thing you need to be looking at:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS; ?></td>
        <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_TOTAL_WEIGHT; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php
function category_list( $category_parent_id = 0, $level = 0 )
{
    // NOTE THE ADDITIION OF THE PARENT ID:
    $sql  = 'select cd.categories_name,c.categories_id, c.parent_id, c.sort_order from ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES . ' c, ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . ' cd where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id AND c.parent_id='.$category_parent_id;
    $res  = tep_db_query( $sql );
    $cats = array();

    while ( $cat = tep_db_fetch_array( $res ) )
    {
        $cats[] = $cat;
    }

    $list = '';
    foreach ( $cats as $cat )
    {
        // start the next row:
        $list .= "<tr class=\"dataTableRow\">\n";
        // The cell for the category needs
        $list .= "<td class=\"dataTableContent\">\n";

        // construct the category link.  Note we are now enclosing 
        // this in a div with a left-indent to show the sub level
        // this category is at.  Adjust the padding-left calculation 
        // to suit your page
        $list .= '<div style="padding-left: ' . (2 * $level) . 'em;">';
        $list .= "&bull; {$cat['categories_name']}";
        $list .= "</div>\n";

        // close the row
        $list .= "</td>\n";
        $list .= "<td class=\"dataTableContent\"></td>\n";
        $list .= "</tr>\n";

        // recurse into the child list, incrementing $level
        $list .= category_list( $cat['categories_id'], 1+$level );
    }

    // return the list
    return $list;

}

echo category_list();
?>
</table>
```

*Note that `<tbody>` is an *implied* element.  It doesn't have to be explicitly defined in the code, but it will always be there in the DOM.

Comment: I tried that method before, but what I essentially want is each element of the list to be in its own separate `<td>` tag. the above method, shows the entire list in one `<td>`

Comment: basically, each list element had to be in its own `<td>`

Comment: okay, you can either use a list or a table, but not both.  See my further edit for an example of how to do it using just a table.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through an array and display the contents as part of a table I would separate your business logic from your display logic a little more. My solution here would look like:

```
<!-- populate the array of data to be displayed -->
<?php $list_items = category_list(); ?>

<!-- start the table, display header rows -->
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
    <td class="dataTableHeadingContent"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_PRODUCTS; ?></td>
    <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right"><?php echo TABLE_HEADING_TOTAL_WEIGHT; ?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dataTableRow">
<td class="dataTableContent">

<ul>
    <!-- iterate over data array, create ul for each member -->
    <?php 
        foreach($list_items as $item) {
    ?>
        <li><?php print $item ?></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<!-- finish the table -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- define function which will populate your array -->
<?php
function category_list( $category_parent_id = 0 )
{
    /* 
      this function will look very similar to the one in the 
      one in the original post but will just return the whole
      array instead of printing out one member.
    */

    // populate $items_list...
    return $items_list;
}
?>
```

Please note I didn't test this incomplete code but the idea should be right.

Comment: This will still produce invalid HTML.  The `<ul>` here will be a child of `<table>` instead of `<td>`

Comment: Better, but you still need to wrap your `TD` in a `TR` :-)

Comment: Incidentally, this doesn't quite address the nested lists that OP is trying to create.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing the following code:

```
    $list_items[] = '<tr class="dataTableRow">';
    $list_items[] = '<td class="dataTableContent"><li>';
```

with:

```
    $list_items[] = "<tr class='dataTableRow'>";
    $list_items[] = "<td class='dataTableContent'><li>";
```